# Why the system.out.println() returns different French characters on French OS

Tags: java, encoding

Hi this is a simple question, don't know the answer myself though...
The output of following code running on a French OS is

```
public class FrenchTest {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] lines = {"Le résultat est", "Nom de l'hôte"};

    for(String line : lines){
        System.out.println("NOW : " + line);
    }   
}
//////////////
c:\share>java FrenchTest
NOW : Le rÃ©sultat est
NOW : Nom de l'hÃ´te

c:\share>CHCP 65001

c:\share>java FrenchTest
NOW : Le rÃ©sultat est
NOW : Nom de l'hÃ´te
```

How come? Where is the encoding gist for this case, it works fine on English version OS, THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

If you change the code page and then tell java to output in UTF-8, it should work.  Note that you will need to choose a unicode (truetype) font - I have Consolas and Lucida Console installed on my machine.

Note as below, I get the last character repeated on my machine using java 1.6.0_23.  Can't really explain this :(

```
msandiford@foo /cygdrive/c/foo
$ javac FrenchTest.java

msandiford@foo /cygdrive/c/foo
$ java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 FrenchTest
NOW : Le résultat estt
NOW : Nom de l'hôtee

msandiford@foo /cygdrive/c/foo
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential problems here:

1. Compile time transcoding problem - the [encoding your compiler uses](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_sourcefiles) to read your source file must match the one your editor uses to save it
2. Runtime transcoding problem - the encoding the console uses to read the data must match the one `System.out` encodes it in

You can sidestep compilation issues by using Unicode escapes:

- `"Le r\u00E9sultat est"`
- `"Nom de l'h\u00F4te"`

By default, number 2 is always wrong on Windows. For compatibility with old DOS programs, cmd.exe uses OEM system encodings by default. This is not the default "ANSI" encoding used by the parts of the Windows system still stuck in pre-Unicode encodings.

You can fix this either by [switching the console encoding](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html#charsets_1252) to windows-1252:

```
>chcp 1252
```

...or by changing the encoding used to emit data to the console encoding. The easiest way to do this is to use [Console](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29). Unlike `System.out`, `System.console()` detects and uses the console encoding. Using `Console` can cause issues with running code in IDEs, but there are [things you can do about that](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html).

I have been [unable to get UTF-8 to work](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html#charsets_javaconsole) with 65001.

*In short, you need to overcome decisions made to preserve backwards compatibility.*

Answer (score 0):

It works on my machine:

- set the file encoding to UTF-8
- set the console encoding to UTF-8

Java uses the OS settings as defaults, but you should change these two.

Comment: Is your machine French OS? Could you be specific on the file setting and console setting both, just to make sure mine is as expected, thanks!

Comment: Yeah..the problem is only seen on French OS

Comment: no, it's not because of the OS, but because you are using default settings. My default settings were also probably ISO-8859-1, but I've changed them to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change encoding on your console. In Windows, it's by using the [CHCP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chcp.mspx?mfr=true) (CHange Control Page) command

E.g.

```
CHCP 65001
```

`65001` changes the control page on your console to be UTF-8.

Comment: Nothing changes after CHCP 65001, I write a test class, please see the quesion update